# PCA equation problem

Tags: equations

I am trying to create the equation shown below but i couldn't, any help ?

[image]

Comment: You should read the great introduction [mathmode](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode)

Comment: What is PCA an abbreviation for?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Principle component analysis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$ X = \{x_n\}^{N}_{n=1} $
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, it worked but it makes a new line and i need to write it within the line with some text before it and some text after it.

Comment: @sherifHaggag:  Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @sherifHaggag: Please read some manual/tutorial of LaTeX, e.g. ["The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf).